# Is -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE needed on modern Linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking at a very old C based project. It adds the `-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` define when building.

Is that preprocessor macro still needed on modern Linux (and if so, why)?

Comment: If you're working on a 32-bit machine, it might make a difference — and does no harm.  If you're working on a 64-bit machine, it probably isn't needed — but it probably does no harm either.  I don't use it when building on 64-bit systems (but I have one makefile where it lurks, not causing trouble).  I don't build on 32-bit systems any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the headers. If you are compiling for 64 bit, `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` will be defined for you every time. This only does anything for 32 bit. And yes this is the switch, if you use modern 32 bit Linux, you still need it to access files > 2GB.

The macro definition changes the size of the file size parameters from 32 to 64 bit in `lseek()` and `fseek()`, changes the system call number for `lseek()` to call `llseek()`, and the size of the file size member of `struct stat` to 64 bit. (The syscall change happens elsewhere for `*stat` unless you still build against libc5.)